# Search through list items on every input key press using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create this search function which hides all `<li>` where HTML is not equal to `<input>` value.

How can I accomplish that with jQuery?

```
$('input').keypress(function(){
    if($('ul li').html != $('input').val()) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: what is <input> value?

Comment: use a .each() loop to loop through each <li> and hide all those <li> that dont match the condition.

Comment: `$('ul li').html` should probably be `$('ul li').html()`, although I'm guessing that you have more than one input and list item, in which case your logic won't work regardless. Post a complete code example please.

Comment: input value is what you type in

Comment: @j08691 what if it's just 1 input and 1 list? :)

Comment: If you have only one list item and one input on the page then it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something more like this:

```
$('input').keypress(function() {
    var inputValue = $("input").val().toLowerCase();
    $("li").each(function() {
         if($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) == -1)
         {
              $(this).hide();
         }
         else
         {
              $(this).show();
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: keep the $("input").val() in a variable outside the each loop so you dont need to retrieve the value each time

Comment: That would indeed be more efficient. So I fixed it.

Comment: @KeithEnlow works just great, is it possible to make it do like:
<input value="Nam">
<li>Name</li>
so this matches

Comment: @KeithEnlow now it hides the match :/

Comment: @Nabil Haha that was my bad! I got my logic switched up, try again. The if statement should be `==` instead of `!=` . Sorry

Answer (score 3):

You should listen to the `keyup` event so that you can get the value of the `<input>` after the keystroke. You could hide all of your list items, [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) out the one that matches, and show it. Compare the values both in lower-case to get a case-insensitive comparison.

Also, comparing the values like that wouldn't strictly 'search' for the value entered, it would only show the item if exactly that were to be typed. You could search through the substrings of each of the `<li>`s HTML of the same length as the value:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('ul li').hide().filter(function(){
        return $(this).html().substring(0, value.length).toLowerCase() == value;
    }).show();
});
```

Remember this won't account for any leading/trailing white-space, but there's [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) for that.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b1pxu8Lt/4/)